# Bootstrap Image's doesn't resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, response, bootstrap-4

So i have the below Layout created

[image: Architecture Images]

This is the Code i used to create the layout

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3 style="margin-top:50px">
        Key Projects
    </h3>       
        <div class="row">               
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">                
              <img id="projectMainImg" src="https://placeimg.com/544/358/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive ">

                </div>
            <div class="row col-lg-6 col-sm-12" >

                        <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">                    

            </div>                
        </div>     
</div>
```

Now my problem is when i go into chrome debugger and resize the screen i get the following 
[image: Responsive Image]

[image: Iphone]

I taught having `col-sm-12` in the div and the `class="img-responsive"` would make the smaller images stack neatly under the big image when the window is resized.

I have spent alot of time on the [BootStrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/) site but i can't figure it out. Can anyone help explain what i need to do?

Comment: Could you place your code as a snippet so everyone could look it themselves and check it in dev tools

Comment: According to bootstrap. There is a class `image-fluid`

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap v4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, have a look. I've replaced all the `img-responsive` on `img-fluid` it works as for me. Moreover, they have classes for margins and paddings so it's better not to use inline.

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h3 style="margin-top:50px">
    Key Projects
  </h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
      <img id="projectMainImg" src="https://placeimg.com/544/358/arch" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="row col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
      <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-fluid">
      <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In latest version of bootstrap **img-responsive** is replaced with **img-fluid** class.

Comment: img-fluid sets image width to 100%. Can you create & share a jsfiddle for the same?

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<h3 style="margin-top:50px">
    Key Projects
</h3>       
<div class="row">               
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">                
          <img id="projectMainImg" src="https://placeimg.com/544/358/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive ">

            </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12" >
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                       <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                       <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                   </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                       <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                       <img id="projectImage" style="height:176px;width:264px;margin:0px 0px 5px 5px" src="https://placeimg.com/264/176/arch" alt="" class="img-responsive">

                   </div>
               </div>
        </div>                
    </div>
```